# If sendo executado com condição falsa

Tags: python, if

Olá, comecei hoje com o python. Estou fazendo um algoritmo que retorna a raiz de um polinômio (2x -4) pelo método da bissecção:

Os métodos que vou utilizar na função principal (bisseccao).

Sendo [a.b] meu intervalo, temRaiz() serve para verificar uma possível mudança de sinal entre f(a) e f(b), se houver, há uma raiz nesse intervalo.

```
def temRaiz(intervalo) :
    if ((2*intervalo[0] - 4)*(2*intervalo[1] - 4) < 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Os métodos abaixo são para diminuir o intervalo pela metade, deslocando apenas um ponto.

```
def cortaIntervaloA(intervalo, ptmedio) :
    intervalo[0] = ptmedio
    return intervalo

def cortaIntervaloB(intervalo, ptmedio) :
    intervalo[1] = ptmedio
    return intervalo
```

Aqui eu recebo os valores do intervalo inicial e logo após a função principal.

```
intervalo = []
intervalo.append(float(input('Digite o primeiro valor do intervalo:')))
intervalo.append(float(input('Digite o segundo valor do interalo:')))

def bisseccao(intervalo) :
    while abs(intervalo[1]-intervalo[0]) > 0:
        acumuladorMedia = (intervalo[1]+intervalo[0])/2
        print(intervalo)
        if temRaiz(cortaIntervaloB(intervalo,acumuladorMedia)):
            cortaIntervaloB(intervalo,acumuladorMedia)
        else:
            print(intervalo)
            cortaIntervaloA(intervalo,acumuladorMedia)
        print(intervalo)

    return acumuladorMedia

print(bisseccao(intervalo))
```

O problema parece estar na estrutura if, a instrução nela é executada mesmo quando a condição retorna False e logo após o else também é executado. (Coloquei as funções print para ajudar a identificar onde estava o erro)

Exemplo (input: 1,6)

```
[1.0, 6.0]
[1.0, 3.5]
[1.0, 3.5]
[1.0, 2.25]
[1.0, 2.25]
[1.0, 1.625] # ** Quando a condição retorna False o ponto B ainda é deslocado
[1.625, 1.625] # ** else executado em seguida
1.625
```

Comment: Nessa linha `if temRaiz(cortaIntervaloB(intervalo,acumuladorMedia)):` você já tá alterando o intervalo e altera novamente quando você executa o `cortaIntervaloB` na linha seguinte, não?

Comment: Então, no começo eu achei que sim, mas olhando o output do exemplo, na linha 2  (o ultimo print(intervalo) da primeira iteração) da pra ver que ele só executou uma vez, se fosse esse o caso, teria executado duas vezes.

Comment: Será que não é uma questao de dar o print antes de chamar a funcao?
Dentro do seu **else**, não deveria chamar o print DEPOIS de chamar a funcao 'cortaIntervaloA'?

Comment: O que acontece é, justamente, porque você está chamando o `cortaIntervaloB` no if. Tenta chamar o `temRaiz`, da seguinte forma: `temRaiz([intervalo[0],acumuladorMedia])` e se ele resolve o seu problema. Lembrando que o ideal é que você coloque uma precisão na subtração do while, senão ele pode ficar em loop infinito com números muito pequenos...

Comment: Obrigado Felipe! Não sabia que era possível chamar uma função dentro de uma condição, pensei que ele armazenava o valor retornado temporariamente apenas para verificação, sem alterar qualquer variável do escopo, vou incluir a precisão no algoritmo.